Trying to recover orphaned tables
As I wrote in a previous post a partition has "broken" and I can no longer access it from boot but I can do it by mounting the partition.
My big problem is to recover two mysql tables that, carelessly, I did not dump.
I copied the MDY, MYI and sdi files from the old partition to the new one but they are not seen by mysql surely because they are not in the informatio-schema.
I then tried to stop MySql, rename /var/lib/mysq and in its place I copied the entire mysql dir from the old partition
I reactivated mysql (systemctl start mysql) and I saw that the whole mechanism had started up. After a couple of minutes, however,
it was still there working and this worried me.
I tried to stop everything with systemctl stop mysql but in /usr/bin/top there was still mysqld that I killed.
Old version is 8.0.31, new version is 8.0.39
Since only the values ​​of the patch release changed I thought it was possible to act as I did.
The question is:

did I wait a short time?
can't it be done even though only the patch release has changed?

In any case, how can I make the aforementioned files visible and have the old-tables active?

try to recover them see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-database-from-myd-myi-frm-files

I have read the various solutions proposed. None of them work. First of all they are more than dated: the .FRM file has been replaced by .sdi for a long time
They proposed installing XAMPP, but this installs MariaDB which overwrites MySql and I don't like that at all
After that, some already take it for granted that the tables are seen by the server

if both servers have the same Version they should work,  maybe you should add the information what ypu tried and which result and post that in your question

In the opening post there are all the operations I made and the version of the 2 servers

no, for every change also in subversion, you need to upgrade the database

Ok. This means I lost my tables.

no, you make virtual machine with the same Version as source database make the suggestions in the first link, then upgrade the database to 8.0.39 and the make a backup and import it into your new database. it takes a bit of time, but it works just fine, and next time backup backup backup like all vital systems

I will try and will backup backup backup :) I'll let you know
